# Can connect to database on server but cannot insert. Works on mamp localhost

Tags: php, ssl, crud

I created a website which was fully functional on my computer's MAMP. When I placed it on the server, everything works well except for the fact that I cannot insert a new user into the DB. I'm partially concerned that the SSL cert is interrupting it, but I don't know enough about this to determine that. To troubleshoot this I did the following:

```
1. confirmed the connection works by returning row numbers and data that I manually placed into the database

2. confirmed openSSL is active/on

3. confirmed proper placement of my ssl certs through a separate site that confirms their presence

4. checked the error log on the server (which showed no errors) and then created a script to cause an error as proof of principle it works

5.confirmed the phpmyadmin user has full privledges

6. I have two user types and scripts that both don't work that worked on MAMP so I'm fairly confident its not poor coding
```

Further, all my php sql statements have built in mysqli_error($conn) which show no errors, and when I attempted a basic

```
 "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('john')"
```

scenario, it was unsuccessful.
My feeling that it is the ssl stems from the fact that my other (non-encrypted) sites don't have this problem. Is there something basic I'm missing?

Comment: When does the insert happen? After a post or get request possibly?

Comment: what  error do you get?

Comment: I receive no errors, it executes the script and then continues like everything worked, but nothing gets inserted into the DB. The insert happens after a post, however I ran just a controlled insert on the main page as part of the main script and still nothing occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the SSL, its your configuration. See into it. If you can insert while doing it in the phpmyadmin with a raw sql, then check your config like the hostname user and db name. What server you are using?

Comment: I will build temples in your name! The phpmyadmin on the linode ubuntu server requires a default for EVERY value, which isn't true of my local host. Thanks a million!

Comment: I tried to upvote but I don't have a solid enough reputation for it to show. Speaking of, why was my question voted down?

Comment: I see you can just check the button below vote counter, there is a check mark. Some users really don't understand your situation thats why they downvoted

Comment: Checked! Thanks, first time poster so I'm still learning the ropes. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Good luck to you